# How to make secure text field dots as custom in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitextfield

I want to change the secure text field dots.

As a default, we are getting secure fields are dots. But I need to change those to

[image: Like this]

I need to change dots to this way any Suggestions, please.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example code that converts your `passwordTextField` dot to a '*', you can modify this to give hearts by using a custom character from any custom font you have:

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
var passwordText = ""

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if textField == passwordTextField {

        var hashPassword = String()
        let newChar = string.first
        let offsetToUpdate = passwordText.index(passwordText.startIndex, offsetBy: range.location)

        if string == "" {
            passwordText.remove(at: offsetToUpdate)
            return true
        }
        else { passwordText.insert(newChar!, at: offsetToUpdate) }

        for _ in 0..<passwordText.count {  hashPassword += "*" }
        textField.text = hashPassword
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```